# Multiple lines with 6 random numbers in each C#

Tags: c#, list, while-loop

I'am trying to write a program that you can input "x" and get "x" amount of rows with 6 random numbers in each row. The code i currently have give the output of "x" amount of identical rows with 6 random numbers each row. This is my code so far

```
    {
        Random random_generator = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        int random_numbers, int_games;

        List<int> lst_numbers = new List<int>();

        if (!int.TryParse(txt_input.Text, out int_games))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid number");
            txt_input.Clear();
            txt_input.Focus();
        }
        else
            while (lst_display.Items.Count < int_games)
            {
                while (lst_numbers.Count < 6)
                {
                    random_numbers = random_generator.Next(1, 45);
                    if (!lst_numbers.Contains(random_numbers))
                    {
                        lst_numbers.Add(random_numbers);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
                lst_display.Items.Add(string.Join(",", lst_numbers));
            }
    }
```

Comment: [`For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop.

Comment: @Reniuz how did you miss "identicle"? :) I'll fix that up

Comment: @Leo [Typoglycemia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typoglycemia) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanna execute the inner loop each time, currently it's only executed once because you are populating the `lst_numbers` on the first iteration.You could replace it with a `for` loop instead:

```
while (lst_display.Items.Count < int_games)
{
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
         random_numbers = random_generator.Next(1, 45);
         if (!lst_numbers.Contains(random_numbers))
         {
             lst_numbers.Add(random_numbers);
         }
    }
    lst_display.Items.Add(string.Join(",", lst_numbers));
    lst_numbers.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be easier?

```
Public String getList(int numbersPerLine,int rows,int from,int to){
 String list ="";
 for(int i = 1;i<= numbersPerLine;i++;){
   for(int j = 1;j<= rows;j++;){
    List += ""+((int)(Math.random()*to)+from)+",";
   }
   list +=\n";//for starting new line... 
 }
 return list;
}
```